# How to create a type that contains multiple namespaces

Tags: spyne

I'm trying to receive and generate messages that can have the following schema:

```
<ns1:data>
  <ns1:status-change/>
  <ns2:rpc-call/>
</ns1:data>
```

I then have:

```
class NS1ComplexModel(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'ns1'

class NS1Data(NS1ComplexModel):

    statusChange = NS1StatusChange
    rpcCall = NS2RPCCall

class NS1StatusChange(NS1ComplexModel):
    ...
```

But the outcome of this is that  has the namespace of `ns1` and not `ns2`.

I've been looking through `resolve_namespace()` and friends and I think I see what's causing it but I can't work out how to fix it or even work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is the same problem I'm having, and I solved it by defining

```
class NS2RPCCall(NS2ComplexModel):
    class Attributes(NS2ComplexModel.Attributes):
        sub_ns = NS1ComplexModel.__namespace__
```

This is from looking at `spyne.protocol.xml.XmlDocument._get_members_etree` and `spyne.model.complex._gen_attrs`.

Comment: That's correct, but I'd suggest doing `rpcCall = NS2RPCCall.customize(sub_ns="NS2")` inline within the parent (in this case: `NS1Data`) object.